# Facing Issue with the decision tree classifier implementation in scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Trying to generate a decision tree in sci-kit learn. I have a CSV file, providing as input to my sci-kit program. When I print the dataset length it is 502, the data set shape is (502, 1).There is only one array.

How do I fit into the decision tree and get a result, not sure if I am doing it correctly, below is my code.

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    from sklearn import tree
    from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
    from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
    from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

    input_file = "output.csv"

    # for tab delimited use:

     df = pd.read_csv(input_file, header = 0, delimiter = "\t")

   # printing the original column values in a python list

     print(df.values)

     print("DataSet Length :",len(df))

     print("DataSet Shape :",df.shape)

    # Assigning values to an array  
     X=df.values[:,0]

   # test train the the data
     X_train,X_test=train_test_split(X,test_size=0.3,random_state=100)

   # Passing to the Decision Tree Classifier, with entropy criterion

    clf_entropy = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = "entropy", rando  
    m_state = 100,max_depth=3, min_samples_leaf=5)

    # Fitting the data  to the classifier
    clf_entropy.fit(X_train)
```

CSV file is on the below link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3XlF206d5UrVnh6QS1LRW0xT0U/view?usp=sharing

Download and open using excel. Referring to the following sci-kit documentation for reference.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier

Comment: Do you know what a shape of ```502,1``` means? Does that make sense for your task (probably not)? (looking at the link it might seem to make sense; but in this case a linear **regressor** might seem more natural; yes, you need to think about classification vs. regression, to me it looks like the latter)

Comment: That means 502 rows and a single column if Iam correct.

Comment: Yes, 502 samples of dimension 1. Again: classification or regression? 2. Why DecisionTrees? 3. What exactly is the question? Fitted allows the call clf_entropy.predict().

Comment: @sascha , actually it is a classification problem , let me explain you the whole case , i have 1000 spam and a non spam emails , i have generated some statistics about all the files , and stored info about each file in a csv file , through the scikit learn i want to classify the infomation ,  you  can look at the csv , download and view it in excel or text editor.

Comment: No, not using only that data. There is no 0 and 1 class. Only 1 input and 1 output, or 2 inputs, as you like. So maybe this file is your transformed input, but any class-information is missing and well... how to learn with that?

Comment: I didn't understand about the class information you are talking about. I tried this   X=df.values[:502,]

Y=df.values[:,0]  , getting a different error while reading the array array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: But you did not use any Y, as outlined my Miriam. Why did you not tell that there is an error (which should happen when y is missing). Apart from that you need some basics about numpy, pandas and maybe scikit-learn on how to prepare your data (you did not even approach the error in fit as your data-processing earlier is broken, which is now clear after your new comment). Using these two columns in a classification-task still makes not much sense to me.

Comment: Can you tell me more about the class information which you were referring to, how to proceed with this problem , the error which i got is related to content in the file , i will figure it out .

Comment: It does not matter. I just gave your "take some data and build two columns (like in your csv)" a name: a transformation of data. As presented currently: this question is missing details, including a full stack-trace of the error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to fit a decision tree classifier, your training and testing data needs to have labels. Using these labels, you can fit the tree. Here is an example from [sklearn website](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html):

```
from sklearn import tree
X = [[0, 0], [1, 1]]
Y = [0, 1]
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X, Y)
```

The problem is that in your code, you have only `X` values, without labels (`Y` values). So you cannot fit the tree.